# Set the value of a cell to be the hyperlink to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I want to set the value of a cell to be the hyperlink to another workbook.
I set the variable "strPath" to be the path that leads to the workbook I want to copy.
However, I am not sure my syntax is correct. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
For index = 3 To 37
    If sheet.Cells(index, 3) = "OPEN" Then
        dateColumn = FindDate(portfolioDate)
        portfolioName = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & index & "").Value

        strPath = "G:\Risk\Risk Reports\VaR-Stress test\" & portfolioDate & "\" & portfolioName & ""

       path = "strPath.xls"

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
        sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn).Hyperlink = path
        wb.Close Savechanges:=False

    End If
Next
```

Comment: This would be dependent on your `portfolioName = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & index & "").Value`... does that include an extension, e.g., .xlsb?  If not you will need to add that into your `strPath`

Comment: What problem are you experiencing exactly? What is `sheet`, `dateColumn` and `portfolioDate`? Does that directory and file exist? A side note: you don't need to add `& ""` at the end of a string concatenation

Comment: portfolioDate is determined through the inputbox and sheet is just the active worksheet

Comment: what will happen if I add the .xls extension?

Comment: @YaraK if you add into your `strPath` & ".xls", then you should be able to specify an actual file.  Just try it, and ensure that it is the same extension as your actual file.  This is all based upon the assumption that your `portfolioname` only reads like "Earning Account Name"  rather than "Earning Account Name.xls"

Comment: I modified the code, but it is giving me an error. you can check out my changes

Comment: @YaraK What error?  We need to know the error code and what line they occur.

Comment: it's giving me a Run-time error '438' on the line ```sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn).Hyperlink = path```

Comment: I think ly syntax is incorrect for the line ```  path = "strPath.xls" ```  I am not sure how to add the ".xls" after the strPath string